# Can I use ADFS for implementing SSO for our Rest Api project in Grails?

Tags: rest, grails, single-sign-on, adfs, adfs3.0

I need to implement SSO using adfs with our current Grails application

So, currently I have 1 main project with other 5 plugin projects used as rest API. Its already setup in grails framework and working flawlessly with 1 security plugin which use LDAP protocol to take care of the authentication for the employees. All of these are wrapped up in a single war so each module uses this LDAP authentication. Now we want to create different wars for all these 5 modules.

We want to implement SSO for this and We already have ADFS server setup for the MS sharepoint access. I have searched and read a lot but nowhere I am able to find a solution for this.

May I please know first of all whether or not it is possible to use ADFS with the current grails framework for implementing SSO.
If yes, can you please guide me how to do it or suggest me some links for the same. If no, what are the other possible solutions for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think that should be possible. Have a look at the ADAL libraries, which are available for Java as well: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries
There's some good tutorials there, too.

These are made for being used with Azure AD, so a cloud-hosted ADFS server, but they work for self-hosted ADFS 4.0 instances, too.